# Run method in a schedule inside a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have a Windows Service, and I need run a method in a specific Schedules. So far I implement a class that represent a schedule.

```
public class SchaduleTime
{
    public int Hour { get; set; }

    public int Minute { get; set; }

    public DateTime Next
    {
        get
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var dt = now.Date;

            // the time has passed to execute today?
            if (Hour * 60 + Minute < now.Hour * 60 + now.Minute)
            {
                dt = dt.AddDays(1);
            }

            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, Hour, Minute, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

And I create a main class that have this fields:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer;
private SchaduleTime[] schadules;
```

And run something like that in Elapsed event of the timer field:

```
private void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // do my work.

    // programing next:
    var nowTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

    // get the next schadule.
    var next = schadules
        .Select(s => new
            {
                Schadule = s,
                IntervalNeeded = s.Next.Ticks - nowTicks
            })
        .OrderBy(o => o.IntervalNeeded)
        .First();

    timer.Enabled = false;
    timer.Stop();

    timer.Interval = (int) new TimeSpan(next.IntervalNeeded).TotalMilliseconds;

    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Start();
}
```

To me this seems like a kludge strategy or spaghetti code, I mean seems ugly.

Is there a way to do this using a specialized class that works with scheduling or something like Windows Task Scheduler inside .net or my approach is good and I'm freaking out?

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider hypothetical situation where you got 10 schedules for 14:00. Say your timer stopped at 13:59:59, what happens is:

- 10 schedules claim they got 1 more second to go
- elapsed handler picks first and restarts itself with 1 second interval
- it stops again at 14:00 - right when all the schedules are already returning `Next` for the following day

As a result, you've run 1 out of your 10 jobs. Doesn't look good.

Of course, you could take list, or make limitation that only 1 job can be set for given hour. But then again, what other assumptions you need to make? Can schedules array be empty? Does it work when there's 1 million schedules? Do you have tests for this code? And so on.

**Instead**, you can use specialized library to do *just that* - [**Quartz**](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/features.html). It's a simple jobs scheduler which can surely do what you're trying to implement here:

```
ISchedulerFactory factory= new StdSchedulerFactory();
IScheduler scheduler = factory.GetScheduler();
scheduler.Start();

// You'll have to implement class performing actual work to be done - ServiceJob
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("ServiceJob", null, typeof(ServiceJob));
Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeDailyTrigger();
// Start time could be anytime today
trigger.StartTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
trigger.Name = "ServiceTrigger";
scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

Quartz takes care of all the timers, running specified jobs at requested time and so forth. It's easy, has good set of [tutorials](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_1.html) and well - you don't have to implement anything.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your approach is fine. Actually, it is sort of inspired. I would not have come up with having one timer and permanently rescheduling it.

What I would have done - and this is strictly optional, like I said, your approach is fine - is just have the timer fire every minute and check if there is something to do. With smaller time resolution, seconds or even milliseconds, I would not do that. But having your timer run every minute, just checking an in-memory-array, and going straight back to sleep in 95% of cases is hardly a terrible waste of resources. Plus, it would allow for code that is much more straightforward and easier to maintain.